# How to appendChild without changing layout of HTML document

Tags: javascript, html

I am using JavaScript to add an event listener which will make text appear inside of a photo on my HTML document when the mouseOver event occurs.  I was successful in adding the event, and when I scroll over the picture my text appears inside of the picture.

My issue is that, although the text appears inside the photo as planned, once the text appears it changes the format of the document and pushes all of the surrounding elements away from it.  I would like to be able to add text within an element without effecting the layout of surrounding elements.

I have tried using innerHTML, appendChild, and textContent to achieve this task.  They are all successful in making my text appear inside the element, but they all have the same issue of pushing surrounding elements away from it.

```
<script>
document.getElementById("box1").addEventListener("mouseover", mouseOver);


function mouseOver() {
    var pictureContent = document.createElement("p");
    pictureContent.textContent = "China, officially the People's Republic of China, is a country in East Asia and the world's most populous country,";
    document.getElementById("box1").appendChild(pictureContent);
} 

</script>
```

Comment: Sounds like more of a CSS issue.

Comment: can you share the html code

Comment: probably want `position:absolute` CSS

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is more of a CSS problem, just add `position: absolute` and positioning styles after creating the element with `style.cssText`.

```
function mouseOver() {
    var pictureContent = document.createElement("p");
    pictureContent.textContent = "China, officially the People's Republic of China, is a country in East Asia and the world's most populous country,";
    pictureContent.style.cssText = "position:absolute"
    document.getElementById("box1").appendChild(pictureContent);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I was able to add the text to the page without effecting the layout of the surrounding elements.  The issue now is that the "position: absolute" means the text will be displayed in-line and I am unable to break it into the chunks needed to fit it into the box that I need to.  Do you have any suggestions for this?

Comment: What do you mean by break into chucks? Are you referring to text wrap?

Comment: Hi James_F.  I found A solution.  I used innerHTML instead of textContent, which allowed me to use <br> to separate lines and ensure the text fit inside the box that I needed it to.  I'm all set here for now, but please let me know if you have any questions or comments.  Thanks for your input!